# How to interpret marginal effect for an ordinal probit model when the independent variables consist of factor scores?

Tags: factor-analysis, marginal-effect, ordered-probit

I conducted an exploratory factor analysis on a 5-point Likert scale utilizing polychoric correlations,  identifying and retaining 4 factors. Subsequently, I computed factor scores through the Anderson-Rubin Method.

Now I want these factor scores to serve as covariates in an ordinal probit regression, with the dependent variables representing different satisfaction levels (1, 2, and 3).
However, the coefficients obtained from the probit regression have limited interpretability, except for their impact on the direction of satisfaction. Therefore, I used marginal effects for the factor scores.

In this context, what would be the interpretation of marginal effects for the factor scores? For instance, can we say that a one-unit increase in "factor score 1" corresponds to a change of x in the estimated probability for outcome 1, y for outcome 2, and z for outcome 3, where x,y, and z are the marginal effects in each category? How does the concept of a "unit change" work for factor scores?

Comment: What is it about factor scores that makes you think the interpretation would differ from any other variable? Also, marginal effects don't consider "unit changes". They are a rate: the rate the outcome changes as the predictor changes. You don't need to run for an hour to talk about your speed in km/hour. Similarly, you don't need to move a whole unit on your predictor to describe the marginal effect.

Comment: THe problem is Factor scores represent the latent constructs identified through factor analysis. These are not directly interpretable in terms of "units" like the original variables, as they are composite scores derived from the underlying factors. In ordinal probit regression, the marginal effects represent the change in the probability of moving from one category to another for a one-unit change in the predictor variable. However, the challenge with factor scores is that they don't have a natural unit interpretation.

Comment: Just divide them by the standard deviation to get Z-scores. Or maybe focus on other measures of association that are not scale dependent (e.g., variance explained). See [Long and Freese (2014)](https://www.stata.com/bookstore/regression-models-categorical-dependent-variables/) Ch 7.8.1, who describe how to fully standardize average marginal effects for ordered probit.

Comment: @Noah thanks a lot. This book was really helpful.